Application launcher that imitates dvd drive only for the app it launches, without drivers nor installation
Is it possible to write an app (for windows) that launches another app and emulates dvd drive Only for that app, without creating additional drives in my computer, without installing additional drivers, without a need to install anything, just launcher. For example I have a pack of games each one of them requires a disk in a drive, I want to be able to run them with a single doubleclick on a launcher configured for the specific game without mounting/unmounting dvd's each time. If there are opensource solutions or developments out there please recommend or give an idea on how possibly this can be implemented. I need exactly a standalone all-in-one launcher that does the job.

"Is it possible...?" - yes. What have you learned? This is not a useful question. Nor is your next question: how? [So] exists for specific focussed questions in programming and software development. This is neither specific nor focussed.

Just tell me that there is hope and give some examples that explain that there is hope, please...
